# Check whether node interleaving is enabled on Dell R710 + Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2008, numa

Is there a way to check whether node interleaving is enabled from *within Windows* on a Dell R710? `omreport chassis biossetup` doesn't appear to print any NUMA-related settings on the server I'm looking at.

Comment: Install Dell OpenManage Server Administrator on the server?

Comment: I don't see it mentioned in OpenManage either, but maybe I overlooked something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this old question today and remembered that I had overlooked it in the output of `omreport chassis biossetup`. The setting is named, unsurprisingly, Node Interleaving. However, in `omconfig`, it's named NUMA. These terms can get rather confusing when changing the setting.

Disable node interleaving (enable NUMA):

```
omconfig chassis biossetup attribute=numa setting=disabled
```

Enable node interleaving (disable NUMA and change back to an SMP-like UMA mode):

```
omconfig chassis biossetup attribute=numa setting=enabled
```

If this sounds odd, then you probably read it correctly. Yes, you set attribute=numa to disabled to turn on NUMA.